# Network reachability and visibility between containers?

Tags: docker, networking

I have two python/flask services that I want to dockerize. One service `s1` is the end-point for the user. The second one, `s2` helps `s1`. So the user calls `s1`, `s1` calls `s2`.

How do I make it so that the ip of `s2` is known to `s1`? How do I do that by minimizing the amount of configuration parameters (ideally, just change only one setting)?

So far `s1`:

```
FROM python:3-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
EXPOSE ${FLASK_RUN_ON_PORT}
CMD [ "python", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0" ]
```

With .env:

```
FLASK_ENV=production
FLASK_APP=s1.py
FLASK_RUN_PORT=5000
```

So far `s2`:

```
FROM python:3-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
CMD [ "python", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0" ]
```

With .env:

```
FLASK_ENV=production
FLASK_APP=s2.py
FLASK_RUN_PORT=5050
```

And docker-compose as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  webservice2:
    build: /path/to/s2
    env_file:
      - /path/to/s2/.env
    ports:
      - ${FLASK_RUN_ON_PORT}:${FLASK_RUN_ON_PORT}
    volumes:
    - .:/code
  webservice1:
    build: /path/to/s1
    env_file:
      - /path/to/s1/.env
    ports:
      - ${FLASK_RUN_ON_PORT}:${FLASK_RUN_ON_PORT}
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - webservice2
```

So, to wrap up. The question is: how do I make it clear to `s1` that `s2` is on port 5050?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not do anything special.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links):

> Links are not required to enable services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name. (See also, [the Links topic in Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links).)

Unless you do something to change the default behavior, both containers will be attached to the same network, and the host `webservice1` will be known from `webservice2` and viceversa.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, `s1` could fire a request with adress `webservice2` and it will be fine?

Comment: From `webservice1` you can reach `webservice2`, and the other way around. These services can reach each other using the service name as host-name.